# file not found error when running python script through tkinter .exe application No Such file or Directory

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created my python script and linked in tkinter UI both .py files are running fine when i ran it visual studio code. But I have converted tkinter UI .py file to .exe file to run my python script in executable file. I have successfuly converted the executable file. But when i run through the executable file(Application) No Such file in directory error coming

'c:\users\username\appdate\local\temp_MEI16402\myprogram.py' no such file or directory

This is temp location

But i have my UI.py,myprogram.py in same location

how to solve this error. Please help.

Comment: This is the function i have written to extract source py file to run in tkinter uI
def openprogram():
    programpath=os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'filename.py'))
    subprocess.call(["python",programpath])

Comment: Are you using pyinstaller to generate the .exe file?

Comment: Yes I am using pyinstaller to generate .exe file

Answer (score 0):

To import `myprogram.py` into `UI.py` you can do this:

```
import myprogram.py
```

The when you build it into an .exe file with pyinstaller you can add the `--onefile` option to build both scripts into one file. Here's an example:

```
pyinstaller --onefile UI.py
```

Comment: I followed your requested steps but after clicking button nothing running

Comment: I followed your steps made some mistakes first second time i corrected it and converted .exe file after when running .exe file my UI not opened it started running directly

Comment: When i run the same code in visual studio code First its myprogram.py after that only it opened Ui.py this is not the way i want. I want to open my UI and click run button after that only it need to run

Comment: Try bundling in myprogram.py when making the exe file

Comment: It didn't work. When i run myprogram.py UI.py is falling in the loop. when i click the button in UI it is opening another UI and click button open UI. It is falling continuous loop.

Comment: When i click close button in the UI program started running